# Prove that any group of order $945$ has at least one subgroup of order $9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, p-groups

I'm trying to solve this group theory problem from my abstract algebra course. It goes like this:

> Prove that any group of order 945 has at least one subgroup of order
> 9.

First, I noticed that $945=3^3\cdot5\cdot7$, and obviously $9=3^2$. I guess the prove will use Sylow theory, finding Sylow $3,5,7$-subgroups, but I'm not sure where to start. If i'm not wrong, there are either $1$ or $7$ Sylow $3$-subgroups in $G$, but I don't know if this is even useful in this problem. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's enough to prove that any group of order $27$ must have a subgroup of order $9$.

Comment: You won't be able to prove an *element* of order $9$ exists, but a subgroup of order $9$ exists by [the basics of Sylow $p$-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Proof_of_the_Sylow_theorems).

Comment: @Alejandro Bergasa Alonso There is a more general theorem, that if $p$ is a prime and $|G|=p^n$ then $G$ contains subgroups of order $p^k$ for all $0\leq k\leq n$. This appeared many times on this forum. For example, you can see my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936407/every-group-with-order-prime-power-pn-then-it-has-subgroup-of-order-pk-for/2936422#2936422

Comment: @Mark Ok, I'll check it now. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove that if $G$ is a group of order $p^{n}$, $p$ a prime and $n\geqslant0$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^{m}$ for all $0\leqslant m\leqslant n$. In fact, we prove by induction in $|G|$ a stronger version of this: If $G$ is a $p$--group of order $p^{n}$, then $G$ has a chain of normal subgroups $1=P_{0}\unlhd P_{1}\unlhd P_{2}\unlhd\cdots\unlhd P_{n}=G$ such that $|P_{i}|=p^{i}$ for all $i=0,\ldots,n$. If $|G|\leqslant p$ we have nothing to prove. If $|G|=p^{n}\geqslant p^{2}$, we assume that the result holds for $p$--groups whose order are less than $|G|=p^{n}$. Since all non-trivial finite $p$--groups have non trivial center, we consider $g\in Z(G)$ whose order is equal $p$. Then $\langle g\rangle\unlhd G$ and we can consider the group $G/\langle g\rangle$, whose order is $p^{n-1}$. By induction we can found a normal chain $$1=\langle g\rangle/\langle g\rangle=P_0/\langle g\rangle\unlhd P_{1}/\langle g\rangle \unlhd\cdots \unlhd P_{n-1}/\langle g\rangle=G/\langle g\rangle$$ such that $|P_{i}/\langle g\rangle|=p^{i}$ for all $i=0,\ldots,n-1$. It follows that for all $i=0,\ldots,n-1$ we have $|P_i|=p^{i+1}$. Writing $H_i=P_{i-1}$ for all $i=1,\ldots, n$ and putting $H_0=1$, we get the chain $1=H_0\unlhd H_{1}=P_{0}=\langle g\rangle\unlhd H_{2}=P_{1}\unlhd\cdots\unlhd H_{n}=P_{n-1}=G$, such that $|H_{0}|=|\{1\}|=1$ and for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ we have $|H_{i}|=|P_{i-1}|=p^{(i-1)+1}=p^{i}$. The claim is now proved.

Finally, since $27=3^{3}$ divides $945$, a group of order 945 has at least one subgroup of order 27 (Sylow theorem), say $H$. By the previous paragraph, $H$ has a subgroup of order 9, say $K$. Then, $K$ is a subgroup of the whole group of order 9.

Comment: And how do you know that there exist some element $g$ of order $3$ inside $Z(G)$? You know it isn't trivial, but how do you know it contains elements of order 3? Thanks for your answer, sorry if my question is trivial.

Comment: Also, how do you prove that chain exists? Thanks for helping.

Comment: First, the proof that I showed holds for all primes $p$, then it holds as well for the prime 3. I think that your question would be: you know that $Z(G)$ is not trivial, but how do you know it contains an element whose order is $p$? This becomes from the well known Cauchy's Theorem which says that if an arbitrary prime $q$ divides the order of a finite group $H$, then $H$ has at least one element of order $q$. So, since $Z(G)$ is not trivial and it is a $p$--group, then $p$ divides the order of $Z(G)$ and by Cauchy's Theorem we get an element $g\in Z(G)$ whose order is $p$.

Comment: Well, I think your second comment is about the group of order 945. Let $H$ be a group order 945. Then, by Sylow Theorem it has a subgroup of order 27, say $G$. Now, we can forget the existence of the group $H$ and focus our atention on the group $G$. Since $|G|=27=3^{3}$, it is a 3--group. By the first comment i did, $G$ has a chain $1=P_{0}\unlhd P_{1}\unlhd P_{2}\unlhd P_{3}=G$ such that, for $i=0,1,2,3$,  $|P_{i}|=3^{i}$. Thus, $|P_{2}|=3^{2}$ and $G$ has a subgroup whose order is 9. Now, we remember the original group $H$. We have $P_2\leq G$ and $G\leq H$ and so $P_2\leq H$, as wanted.

Comment: Sorry if I was not precisely clear. I'm Brazilian and I'm still learning English.

Comment: Ok I now see, it's a lot clearer now. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: you're welcome.